# Android Studio/Firebase: Trying to retrieve all data but only getting the last item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an app that displays jobs added by users on a map. In order to do this, I am trying to create a realtime Firebase Database that stores all jobs:

[image: Image of Firebase Database Json Tree]

In the onCreate method, markers(jobs) will be added from the list of all current jobs in the Firebase database.

Here is my code so far:

```
        DatabaseReference ref1 = database.getReference();
        DatabaseReference jobsReference = ref1.child("Jobs");

        jobsReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                jobs = new ArrayList<>();
                // AddJobHandler is the object I use to store the jobs
                for(DataSnapshot jobSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    AddJobHandler newJob = jobSnapShot.getValue(AddJobHandler.class);
                    jobs.add(newJob);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) {
                    Toast.makeText(map.this, jobs.get(i).getDesc(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

When I run the app, I get 3 toasts, but titles that are of the most recent job added. How can I add all of the jobs to the jobs ArrayList from the database?

TL; DR: The jobs ArrayList only seems to add the most recent job. How can I get the *ArrayList* to add all of the jobs that are in the Firebase Realtime Database

Comment: I don't see any problem in toasting different values. Try adding breakpoints via debugger so that you check where things go wrong

Comment: @Killer I used the debugger and breakpoints to check the ArrayList and everything seems to be working fine. Are you sure my code is fine?

Comment: You're missing something like `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of `onDataChange`. Without that your adapter won't know that the data has changed, and the view won't be updated.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What do you mean. Where would I declare the adapter?

Comment: Hmm... maybe I misunderstood the problem. If your code shows 3 toasts for 3 items, that sounds great. What code isn't working?

Comment: @TamirOffen **how can I add all of the jobs to the jobs ArrayList from the database** I believe you already doing that by `jobs.add(newJob);` which you should check the `ArrayList`. This is a confusing question without even checking `ArrayList` and putting some information about `ArrayList`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No frank, the OP is trying to save the `DataSnapShot` to an `ArrayList` and not the `Adapter`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The problem that I am having is that the ArrayList is filled by the 3 same most recent jobs.

Comment: @TamirOffen How many jobs do you have un your database? Why do say that you get only three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Seems like there is only one change needed in your code, Please check this,**

```
jobs = new ArrayList<>(); //write this in onCreate(); or while declaration in global scope.
```

**Your code  Below**

```
            DatabaseReference ref1 = database.getReference();
            DatabaseReference jobsReference = ref1.child("Jobs");

            jobsReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    // AddJobHandler is the object I use to store the jobs
                    for(DataSnapshot jobSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        AddJobHandler newJob = jobSnapShot.getValue(AddJobHandler.class);
                        jobs.add(newJob);
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) {
                        Toast.makeText(map.this, jobs.get(i).getDesc(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time that you get an event in dataSnapshot you create new ArrayList, so you have just last. try to do `jobs = new ArrayList<>();` in constructor of class or in some another place. it must be fired once.
Also it good to check `if (dataSnapshot.exist)` before some actions with it.

Comment: I am trying to make an ArrayList with all of the Jobs from the database in it. Your solution gives an empty List.

Comment: It because you make `jobs = new ArrayList<>();` in function `onDataChange`. Try to do this in constructor of the class. And bring back your foreach, because my option for query on child value.